# Number of answers is not visible for questions with an accepted answer in the favorites tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bookmarks

I was reviewing the favorites tab in my DSP.SE profile page, when I realized that the number of answers is not visible for those questions with an accepted answer. On the other hand, questions without an accepted answer do show the number of answers correctly, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

I am running 64-bit Windows 8.1 and I have observed this behavior in the following web browsers:

- Firefox 50.0.2
- Google Chrome 54.0.2840.99 m (64-bit)

In both cases I restarted the browsers a couple of times to be sure that the problem was still persistent.

Comment: Probably related to [these problems](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/a/1423/4298), some of which (all?) have been solved by now.

Comment: I've just asked a [related question](http://meta.dsp.stackexchange.com/q/1456/4298) about another occurrence of that bug.

Comment: Hi Cebri, thanks for reporting this bug! It should be fixed now, can you confirm?

Comment: @TedGoas I confirm that it is working properly on both browsers (see [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRa7M.png)). Thanks Ted for taking care of this.