# Another little bug in the display of answer scores for accepted answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Just adding to [this related question](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1455/4298):

In user profiles under Activity => Answers [or Favorites / Bounties] there's a similar problem:

[image]

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for reporting this bug! It should be fixed now, can you confirm?

Comment: @TedGoas: Yes, it's fixed. Thanks!

Comment: @TedGoas For some reason this bug is happening again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKbUN.png

Comment: @codeaviator This should be fixed. Long story short, we took on a considerable amount of technical debt by [making these a circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn27A.png). By reverting this to a rectangle like most of the SE network, this should be fixed and similar bugs should not appear in the future.

Comment: @TedGoas As the proverb goes: "*if it ain't broke, don't fix it*" :) Everything is working fine again. Thank you.